# Postfix: either sending mails or resolving aliases works

Tags: postfix

I want to use Postfix 2.11 on Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS (only) to forward mails send to local user accounts to corresponding mailboxes using another SMTP server.

Configuration:

```
$ postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = localhost mydomain.tld, myhostname, localhost.localdomain, localhost
myhostname = myhostname
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost = my-target-smtp-server
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes

$ cat /etc/aliases
root: some-account@mydomain.tld
```

If I send a mail to the root user

```
$ echo "body"| mail -s "test" root
```

I see the following log entries in */var/log/mail.log*

```
Nov  6 12:40:19 myhostname postfix/pickup[1854]: BD20144EC2: uid=0 from=<root>
Nov  6 12:40:19 myhostname postfix/cleanup[1898]: BD20144EC2: message-id=<20151106114019.BD20144EC2@myhostname>
Nov  6 12:40:19 myhostname postfix/qmgr[1855]: BD20144EC2: from=<root@mydomain.tld>, size=414, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov  6 12:40:19 myhostname postfix/local[1901]: BD20144EC2: to=<some-account@mydomain.tld>, orig_to=<root>, relay=local, delay=0.15, delays=0.11/0/0/0.03, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (unknown user: "some-account")
Nov  6 12:40:19 myhostname postfix/cleanup[1898]: D21A344EC4: message-id=<20151106114019.D21A344EC4@myhostname>
Nov  6 12:40:19 myhostname postfix/bounce[1902]: BD20144EC2: sender non-delivery notification: D21A344EC4
Nov  6 12:40:19 myhostname postfix/qmgr[1855]: D21A344EC4: from=<>, size=2165, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov  6 12:40:19 myhostname postfix/qmgr[1855]: BD20144EC2: removed
Nov  6 12:40:19 myhostname postfix/local[1901]: D21A344EC4: to=<some-account@mydomain.tld>, orig_to=<root@mydomain.tld>, relay=local, delay=0.07, delays=0.03/0/0/0.03, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (unknown user: "some-account")
Nov  6 12:40:19 myhostname postfix/qmgr[1855]: D21A344EC4: removed
```

So for what reason ever postfix won't use the relay server to forward the mail. If I removed 'mydomain.tld' from *mydestination*, mails are properly sent through the SMTP Server provided as *relayhost*, but all information in */etc/aliases* is silently ignored: the mail is sent to *root@mydomain.tld* instead of *some-account@mydomain.tld*.

Do you have any idea what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you should remove "mydomain.tld" from mydestination. 
There also must be a comma between entries in mydestination (you have written localhost  mydomain.tld).

Have you run the "newaliases" command after modifying /etc/aliases ?